# display_timestamp_format issue on CQL

Tags: cassandra, copy, cqlsh

I got an `CQLSH` timestamp format error when I attempt to execute a `COPY` command.

`Shell instance has no attribute 'display_timestamp_format'`

Does anybody know any clue to get rid of this error?

cqlshrc has the entry:
[ui]

```
time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z
```

versions:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.11.872 | DSE 4.8.1 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]
```

Comment: Can you paste your exact COPY command?

Comment: cqlsh:har> copy s1d (id) to '/tmp/output.csv';
Shell instance has no attribute 'display_timestamp_format'
cqlsh:har> copy s1d (id) to '/tmp/output.csv' with time_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z';
Shell instance has no attribute 'display_timestamp_format'
cqlsh:har>

Comment: Ok, also post your `CREATE TABLE` statement.  I don't need the whole thing; but definitely the columns and types, PRIMARY KEY definition, and CLUSTERING ORDER.

Comment: CREATE TABLE if not exists har.s1d (
 ID uuid,
 DATE_OBS timestamp,  
 MJD_OBS double, 

 FILENAME text,
 PROGRAM text,
 RA_DEG float, 
 DEC_DEG float,
 EL float,
 COORDS text,
 
 HIERARCH_TNG_TEL_TARG_ALPHA text, 
 HIERARCH_TNG_TEL_TARG_DELTA text, 
 EXPTIME float,

 NAXIS1 int,
 CRVAL1 float,
 CDELT1 float, 
 
 HIERARCH_TNG_DRS_BJD float, 
 HIERARCH_TNG_DRS_BERV float, 

 HIERARCH_TNG_OBS_TARG_NAME text, 
 HIERARCH_TNG_TPL_NAME text,
 HIERARCH_TNG_TEL_TARG_MAG float,
 HIERARCH_TNG_TEL_TARG_SPTYPE text, 
 
 SPECFLUX text,
 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

Comment: hi, I've just skipped some columns cause the size is bigger than the max allowed characters. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with a workaround, affecting your specific version.

Have a look at the below page for a more complete explanation.

You will need to download 4.8.3 and replace the existing cqlsh command in 4.8.1 with the one from 4.8.3

https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207478053-cqlsh-COPY-command-fails-with-Shell-instance-has-no-attribute-display-timestamp-format-